# Issue using Lightning Component on a Customer Community Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning

I recieve the below error when I am trying to call a Custom Lightning Component in a Visualforce page that is used in Communities.

Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.

logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

CommunityHomePage:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (lightning/lightning.out.delegate.js?v=ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A:143)

**My Component**

```
<aura:component controller="LeadController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="theLead" 
        type="Lead" 
        default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Lead',
                   'Rating__c': 2,
                   'Company': '',
                   'FirstName': '',
                   'LastName': '',
                   'Email': '' }"/>
    <form>

        <ui:inputText value="{!v.theLead.Company}" label="Company" class="input"/>
        <ui:inputText value="{!v.theLead.FirstName}" label="First" class="input"/>
        <ui:inputText value="{!v.theLead.LastName}" label="Last" class="input" />
        <ui:inputEmail value="{!v.theLead.Email}" label="Email" class="input" />
        <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

**My Lightning App is**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:CommunityChatter"/>
</aura:application>
```

**My VF Page is**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Site.BaseUrl}/lightning/lightning.out.js"/>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:MyLightApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:CommunityChatter",
                {},
                "theLead",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log("Component created!");
                    console.log(cmp);
                });
            });
    </script>

    <div id="theLead"></div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Answer:

Since, I was trying to use this component in Customer Communities, I have to make the object available for the customer community profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Issue, It is  just a Permission on the Profile for Lead.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe it will help some people in the future with the same problem.

Comment: Hi Martin, Sorry should have been more specific. Details are as below.