# Lightning Out error with community user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-out

I have a Visualforce page that has a Lightning Component being loaded with it (basically, the VF is a container for the Component).

The code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:includeLightning/>
    <div id="ltng">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $Lightning.use('c:InvoiceGenerator', function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent('c:InvoiceCreator', {}, 'ltng', function() { console.log('loaded!') })
            })
        </script>
    </div>  
</apex:page>
```

The problem is that I can not access it with a Partner Community user, but I can access it just fine on both sandbox (Summer 17) and production (Spring 17) as an admin user, so Locker Service doesn't seem to be issue here.

When accessing the page as a community user, the following error is logged to the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1496073716760:143)
```

The component's app contains the following lines:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <c:InvoiceCreator></c:InvoiceCreator>
</aura:application>
```

Am I right to assume that this is a bug, or Lighning Out isn't available to community users at all?

## edit

I decided to inspect the error that was shown in Chrome, and I've noticed that it is an error when handling another error from the server. Somewhere on `lightning.out.delegate.js` theres a piece of JS that is used to handle errors, that has these lines:

```
var exceptn = JSON.parse(jsonExcptn);
displayErrorText(exceptn.message);
```

And when trying to parse `jsonExcptn`, the script throws an error, because `jsonExcptn` is not a valid JSON string. It contains the typical internal server error message. More specifically, this is the variable content:

```
"while(1);
*/{
  "message":"Erro interno do servidor\\nID do erro: 340480800-85527 (1241894257)"
}"
```

Comment: Did you implement the appropriate interfaces on the component/app

Comment: @Eric I believe so. I've included the app's code, and I also want to remember that I can access the page normally, but my community users don't. Also updated with some information I got from inspecting the exception with Chrome.

Comment: Is this an authenticated community? If not you need to implement - ltng:allowGuestAccess. Also have a look at: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169065/issue-using-lightning-component-on-a-customer-community-visualforce-page/169066

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove all content from your invoice creator component and just add like a p tag or output text and put some content and see if it comes. This will isolate if the issue is because of the component inside VF out or not

Comment: But the component/page works just fine with non-community users (and is already deployed to production, so no chance removing all the code and replacing it with a tag to isolate the issue).